# connections on Lie groupoids/differentiable stacks

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, stacks

Let $(\Gamma_1\rightrightarrows \Gamma_0)$ be a Lie groupoid.

There [are](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0001870805002471?token=78B50A485B755730B16A6DB308B04738F71252309134AAF9CFF3C2DE991015C50956C0B134E956D9F55F1CC36D8CD8DB) [many](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.04365.pdf) [places](http://users.uoa.gr/~evassil/PAPERS/Univ_Conn_Groupoids.pdf) which define the notion of connection on a Lie groupoid.

As far as I have seen, there is no mention of these notions inducing notion of connection on associated differentiable stack; that is if the notion of connection is Morita invariant.

1. Are there any versions of connections on Lie groupoids that induce notion of connection on a differentiable stack?
2. Are there any notion of connection on a differentiable stack (or algebraic stack)?